# Apps won't start (lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, intel

some applications do not start for me. Of the system ones, these are: discover, 2048-Qt.[image]

Comment: 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2. How did you install the app?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, FYI: the wallpaper is for 20.04 (default), the apps mentioned are included by default....   I wonder if it's video card related (due to `openbox` border being all that is shown) but I don't have time to respond/think-about it currently

Comment: What is the output when you run `2048-qt` from the terminal?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, segmentation fault(core dumped)